# Using Angular 2 components on existing ASP.NET web pages

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2015, npm

I am trying to move the front-end part of a website to Angular 2.
Currently I have really big **ASP.NET 4.5** website.

I would like to create a separated **Angular 2** project as it will be growing with time (and hopefully replace the asp.net) 
For now I would like to create this project in **Visual Studio (2015)** and use some angular components or modules in the actual **ASP.NET** website. 
Does the angular AppModule as to be in the ASP website?

I made some research but could not find answers or examples.

Am I gonna be able to do this relying on **npm** and **system.js** ? I saw that a lot of people are using **gulp** for copying file.

Is there a "right" way of doing this?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Not related to visual studio at all, but yes, you can accomplish this. As you have suggested you can (and should) maintain the Angular application as a separate project. The only additions that you need to make to your aspx page are including SystemJS and its configuration via script tags, importing your application via `SystemJS.import`, and adding a markup tag with the selector corresponding to the app's root element, say 'app', to your aspx markup.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I managed to do this using System.js.import

Comment: Really glad that worked for you. I have used that approach with AngularJS (Angular 1) apps/widgets on .aspx pages many times but had never done it specifically with Angular 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not specific to Visual Studio, but yes, you can certainly accomplish this.

As you have suggested you can and should maintain the Angular application as a separate project.

The only additions that you need to make to your .aspx page are

1. including SystemJS and its configuration via script tags in that page or in its Master Page (You can also do this dynamically for CMS pages and using all sorts of other strategies). For example

   ```
    <script src="loction-of-systemjs.js"></script>
    <script src="loction-of-systemjs.config.js"></script>
   ```
2. Adding a markup tag with the selector corresponding to the app's root element, say **'my-embeddedable-widget'**, to your .aspx markup. For example

   ```
   <my-embeddedable-widget>Loading...</my-embeddedable-widget>
   ```
3. Importing your application via `SystemJS.import` from a script tag embedded in the page containing the component selector above. For example

   ```
   <script> 
     SystemJS.import('my-embeddedable-widget')
       .catch (function(e) {
         console.error(e);
       }); // not using .bind or => here since aspx tends to imply older browser support
   </script>
   ```

Note that this presupposes two things

1. that the **'my-embeddedable-widget'** is set up in your SystemJS configuration. For example

   ```
   SystemJS.config({
     packages: {
       'my-embeddedable-widget': {
         main: 'main.ts' // just an example, could be main.js or anything really
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   If it is not you can add the config entry above as appropriate for your app (strongly recommended) or just import it directly from the path to the app's entry point such as e.g. my-embeddedable-widget/main.ts or my-embeddedable-widget/main.js.
2. That the entry point of your widget declares all of its platform level dependencies, such as **zone.js** and likely various polyfills. For example

   **my-embeddedable-widget/main.ts**

   ```
   import 'zone.js';
   import 'core-js';
   // ...
   import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
   // ....
   ```

   This means that SystemJS will automatically load them when your widget is requested. While you could bring them in via separate script tags as we do with the loader itself, making them explicit dependencies of our widget by using ES Modules improves maintainability and allows us to defer loading them until they are required. Furthermore it helps further decouple the widget from the .aspx page. However, if other JavaScript on the page requires these polyfills, you may need to adjust this approach (especially with respect to **zone.js** because it monkey patches `window.Promise`)

Comment: I try to create based on above example code but its not working so can you provide working code of application on jsfiddle / plinkar will help me to implement